# Unity tilemap problem: The tilemap appears fine in the Scene tab but it doesnt appear as it should in Game tab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, assets, game-development

I've used tile palette and painted the background of my mobile game. It looks as it should in the Scene tab but not in the Game tab nor on the main camera.

This is what it looks like on the scene tab (what I want it to look like):

[image]

I've tried changing the camera's position and clipping planes numbers but it didn't do anything.

Changing the tilemap's tile anchor numbers did change the image but nothing close to what I wanted.

Do you have any suggestions on what this may be about?

This is what it looks like on the game tab and on the main camera:

[image]

Comment: The camera view is visible from the scene, chances are you have something in the wrong place. such as the plane/quad with the background on it